# how do I increase stack trace of gulp task?

Tags: node.js, gulp

```
$ gulp patch
[17:13:27] Requiring external module coffee-script/register
[17:13:28] Using gulpfile ~/source/sem-campaign.js/gulpfile.coffee
[17:13:28] Starting 'bump'...
[17:13:28] Starting 'add'...
[17:13:28] Bumped version to: 1.0.2
[17:13:28] Bumped version to: 1.0.2
[17:13:28] Finished 'bump' after 31 ms
[17:13:28]
[17:13:28] Finished 'add' after 30 ms
[17:13:28] Starting 'commit'...
[?] enter a commit msg, eg initial commit: initial commit
[17:13:32] Finished 'commit' after 3.26 s
[17:13:32] Starting 'patch'...
no buddy
[17:13:32] Finished 'patch' after 25 μs

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Command failed:
  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
  at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

It's hard for me to tell where my gulp task is failing and why. How can I increase the default stack trace?

Comment: There are some plugins which can help you: [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-debug) or [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-plumber) are shown helpful informations about errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add comments and plumber:

1. Add this helper method:

   log = (msg) -> 
     console.log msg
     # you're going to receive Vinyl files as chunks
     transform = (file, cb) ->
       # read and modify file contents
       # file.contents = new Buffer(String(file.contents) + ' some modified content');

   ```
   # if there was some error, just pass as the first parameter here
   cb(null, file);
   ```

   # returning the map will cause your transform function to be called
     # for each one of the chunks (files) you receive. And when this stream
     # receives a 'end' signal, it will end as well.
     # 
     # Additionally, you want to require the `event-stream` somewhere else.
     return eventStream.map(transform);
2. pipe thw log method between steps in a task:

   gulp.task 'myTask', ->
     gulp.src myCss,
       base: myBase
     .pipe log "Got css files!"
     .pipe concat 'app.css'
     .pipe log "concated css!!"

this is written in coffeescript, you can turn it to javascript here:
http://js2coffee.org/

3. create a catch error helper method:

   catchError = (err) ->
     plugins.util.beep() # [ref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-load-plugins);
     console.log err
4. add plumber to plugins:

   gulp.task 'myTask', ->
     gulp.src myCss,
       base: myBase
     .pipe plugins.plumber
       errorHandler: catchError
     .pipe log "Got css files!"
     .pipe concat 'app.css'
     .pipe log "concated css!!"

Done! :)

More resources to check out:
[gulp-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-print)
[gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug)