# See full stack trace on gulp exception

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, postmortem-debugging

A gulp watch task keeps throwing an exception with a stack trace that is limited to 10 frames, so I can't tell where it's originating.  I'm guessing this must be configurable somewhere but I can't determine where.  I looked in gulp.config.js and in gulp.util.js.  I read [this report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197238/how-do-i-increase-stack-trace-of-gulp-task) but I think it must be easier than that.

Who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
gulp.on('err', function(e) {
    console.log(e.stack);
});
```

Comment: Didn't work. Output says the error is from gulp-babel.

Comment: It should be simply `e.stack`

Answer (score 1):

It's super cute how they make everything completely and utterly useless. A stacktrace that tells you nothing, great, that's really useful ... great idea.

Your fix is to run things "manually" like this

```
$ node --stack-trace-limit=5000 --stack-size=10000 $(which gulp) ...
```